# Java - Reading files into array

Tags: java, load, save

I want to save a library for a small scale java application which stores technical manuals. Right now I am able to save the library to an external file but I am unable to load it back into the library itself, currently "-1" just gets printed to the console.

How can I solve this?

Here is my code:

```
            //Choice 7: Load Library:

            if(Menu.menuChoice == 7){
                boolean loadYesNo = Console.readYesNo("\n\nThe manualKeeper app is able to load and display any 'Library.txt' files \nfound in your home folder directory.\n\nWould you like to load and display library? (Y/N):\n");
                String fileName = "Library.bin";
                if(loadYesNo==true){
                    try {
                        FileInputStream fileIs = new FileInputStream(fileName);
                        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fileIs);
                        int x = is.read();
                        System.out.println(x);
                        is.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Menu.displayMenu();
                }
                else if(loadYesNo==false){
                    System.out.println("\n\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("\n                             Library not loaded!\n");
                    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                    Menu.displayMenu();
                }
            }


            //Choice 0: Exit the program:

            if(Menu.menuChoice == 0){
                if(Menu.menuChoice == 0){
                    if(Library.ManualList.size() > 0){
                        boolean saveYesNo = Console.readYesNo("\nThe manualKeeper app is able to save your current library to a '.txt' \nfile in your home folder directory (C:\\Users\\ 'YOUR NAME').\n\nWould you like to save the current library? (Y/N):\n");
                        String fileName = "Library.bin";
                        if(saveYesNo==true){
                            try {
                                FileOutputStream fileOs = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
                                ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOs);
                                for (int i = 0; i < Library.ManualList.size(); i++){
                                    os.writeObject(Library.ManualList.get(i).displayManual());
                                    os.close();
                                }
                            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            System.out.println("DONE WRITING!");

                        } else if(saveYesNo==false){
                            System.out.println("\n\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                            System.out.println("\n                              Library not saved!\n");
                            System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                            break exit;
                        }
                        Menu.displayMenu();
                    }else if(Library.ManualList.isEmpty()){ 
                        Menu.displayMenu();
                    }
                }
            }               

        }
        System.out.println("\n              ~   You have exited the manualKeeper app!   ~                  ");
        System.out.println("\n                  Developed by Oscar Moore - 2014 - UWL\n");
        System.out.println("\n                                   <3\n");

    }
}
```

Here is also my library class:

```
package library;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Library {  

    public static int ManualChoice;

    static String returnManualTitle;

    static String status1 = "Available";

    static String status2 = "Borrowed"; 

    public static ArrayList<Manual> ManualList = new ArrayList<Manual>();
    static ArrayList<Manual> borrowedManuals = new ArrayList<Manual>();

    static void addManual(){
        Manual newManual = new Manual(); 
        newManual.createManual();
        ManualList.add(newManual);
        System.out.println("\n\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("\n                          Manual added to library!\n");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    }

    static void displayManualList(){
        if (ManualList.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(Messages.empltyLibraryMessage + Messages.tryAgainMessage);
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------");
            Menu.menuChoice = 8;

        } else {    
            System.out.printf("\n\nHere are the Manual/s currently stored in the library:\n\n\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < ManualList.size(); i++){
                System.out.printf("-------------------- Index Number: %s --------------------\n",i);
                System.out.println(ManualList.get(i).displayManual());  
                System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------\n");
            }
        }
    }

    static void displayBorrowedManuals(){
        if (ManualList.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(Messages.empltyLibraryMessage + Messages.tryAgainMessage);
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------");
            Menu.menuChoice = 8;

        } else {                    
            for (int i = 0; i < borrowedManuals.size(); i++){
                System.out.printf("-------------------- Index Number: %s --------------------\n",i);
                System.out.println(borrowedManuals.get(i).displayManual()); 
                System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void borrowManual(){

        displayManualList();
        ManualChoice = (Console.readInteger(Messages.enterManualIndexMessage, Messages.ManualIndexNotInListMessage, 0, Library.ManualList.size() - 1));

        borrowLoop:
        while(Menu.menuChoice == 3){

            if ((ManualList.get(ManualChoice).status.equalsIgnoreCase(status1)) && (ManualList.size() >= ManualChoice)){
                ManualList.get(ManualChoice).status = "Borrowed";
                ManualList.get(ManualChoice).borrower = User.userName;
                ManualList.get(ManualChoice).borrowDate = "Today.";
                ManualList.get(ManualChoice).returnDate = "In two weeks.";
                borrowedManuals.add(ManualList.get(ManualChoice));
                System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("\n                             Manual borrowed!\n");
                System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                break borrowLoop;

            }else if(ManualList.get(ManualChoice).status.equalsIgnoreCase(status2) && ManualList.size() >= ManualChoice){
                System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("\n            "
                        + " The Manual you wish to borrow is already on loan.");
                System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                break borrowLoop;

            }else if(ManualChoice > ManualList.size()-1){
                System.out.println(Messages.noSuchManualMessage);
                break borrowLoop;
            }
            if(ManualList.size() > 1){
                displayManualList();
            }
            else if(ManualList.size() == 1){
                ManualList.get(ManualChoice).status = "Borrowed";
                ManualList.get(ManualChoice).borrower = User.userName;
                ManualList.get(ManualChoice).borrowDate = "Today.";
                ManualList.get(ManualChoice).returnDate = "In two weeks.";
                borrowedManuals.add(ManualList.get(ManualChoice));
                System.out.printf("\n\n %s\n\n", ManualList.get(ManualChoice).displayManual());
                System.out.println("Please return the Manual within two weeks!\n");
                displayManualList();
            }
        }
        Menu.displayMenu();
    }

    static void returnManual(){
        System.out.printf("\n\nHere are the Manual/s currently out on loan:\n\n");

        if(borrowedManuals.size() > 0){
            for (int i = 0; i < borrowedManuals.size(); i++)
                System.out.println(borrowedManuals.get(i).displayManual());
            returnManualTitle = Console.readString(Messages.enterManualSerial, Messages.tooShortMessage, 3);
        }

        int x = 0;
        boolean serialExistance = false;
        while (x < ManualList.size()){

            if (ManualList.get(x).serial.equalsIgnoreCase(returnManualTitle)){

                ManualList.get(x).status = "Available";
                ManualList.get(x).borrower = "N/A";
                ManualList.get(x).borrowDate = "N/A";
                ManualList.get(x).returnDate = "N/A";

                int p = 0;
                while (p < borrowedManuals.size()) {
                    Manual borrowed = borrowedManuals.get(p);
                    if (borrowed.serial.equalsIgnoreCase(returnManualTitle)) {
                        borrowedManuals.remove(p);
                        break;
                    }
                    p++;
                }               
                System.out.println(Messages.successReturnMessage);
                serialExistance = true;

                break;
            }
            x = x+1;
        }
        if(serialExistance == false){
            boolean repeatReturnManual = Console.readYesNo("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------" + "\n\nThe Manual with the serial "+"\""+returnManualTitle +"\""+ " wasn't found!"
                                                            +"\n\nDo you want to try again? (Y/N):\n");
            System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            if(repeatReturnManual){
                returnManual();
            }
        }else if(serialExistance){
            Menu.menuChoice = 8;
        }               
    }

    public static void removeManual(){

        if(ManualList.size() >0){
            displayManualList();
            ManualChoice = Console.readInteger(Messages.enterRemoveManualIndex ,Messages.ManualIndexNotInListMessage, 0, ManualList.size());        
            int p = 0;
            while (p < borrowedManuals.size()){

                if (borrowedManuals.get(p).title.equalsIgnoreCase(returnManualTitle)){

                    borrowedManuals.remove(p);
                }
            }
            ManualList.remove(ManualChoice);
            System.out.print(Messages.successRemovedManualMessages);
            Menu.menuChoice = 8;
        }               
    }

    static void emptyLibrary(){
        System.out.println("\n                                 WARNING!");
        System.out.println("\n           You have chosen to delete all Manuals in the library.\n"); 
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        boolean emptyLibraryChoice = Console.readYesNo("\nAre you sure you wish to destroy the library? (Y/N): \n");
        System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        if(emptyLibraryChoice){
            Library.ManualList.clear();
            System.out.println(Messages.successEmptyLibraryMesssage);
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            Menu.menuChoice = 8;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ObjectInputStream` not in the intended manner. The correct way would be like:

```
ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fileIs);
Library x = (Library) is.readObject();  // change Library to the type of object you are reading
System.out.println(x);
```

You probably need to change Library, but I could not find out, what type of object you are reading.